# AJAX Request returning some form of long string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

Something weird is going on, my AJAX Request is returning a array but the whole thing is a string itself.

This basically sums it up:

**PHP**

```
$item = array();

$item[] = array(
    'title'     => 'awesome title',
    'permalink' => 'some url'
);

json_encode($item);
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'a_grid_callback',
        type: method
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        console.debug(msg);
    }
});
```

The debug returns this:

```
[{"title":"awesome title","permalink":"some url"}]0
```

If I was to do `alert(msg.length)` I would get a long number equivalent to the length of the code above.

[image]

Comment: Try to set `dataType: json` Looks like the browser is interpreting the response as a string.

Comment: I tried that already and I got no response at all :/

Comment: For some odd reason it's worked now. This is all due to the effects of staying up for nearly 48 hours! Write it as an answer and you get the tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `dataType: 'json'` Looks like the browser is interpreting the response as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$item = array(
    'title'     => 'awesome title',
    'permalink' => 'some url'
);

json_encode($item);


// Add exit here
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this may have had something to do with why `dataType: 'JSON'` wasn't working earlier, I forgot to exit/die.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'a_grid_callback',
        type: method
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        eval("data="+msg);
        var title = data.title;
        console.debug(title);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-associative arrays output as arrays

You'll have to do something like this

```
json_encode($item, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

or this

```
$item[foo] = array(
    'title'     => 'awesome title',
    'permalink' => 'some url'
);
```

or this

```
$item = array(
    'title'     => 'awesome title',
    'permalink' => 'some url'
);
```